# Change the text of the button from ViewController which presented modally

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

There is just a button `rimB`, in `GeneralChooser` controller when i clicking on it, i call `ChooserPopupViewController` which presented modally, where info is returned back when i click on a row , to the previous `GeneralChooser` controller and displayed in `ViewDidLoad ()`

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let controller = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "GeneralChooser") as! GeneralChooser
controller.idSet = idAr[indexPath.row]
controller.nameSet = nameAr[indexPath.row]
dismiss(animated: true)
present(controller, animated: false, completion: nil)
```

in `ViewDidLoad ()` in `GeneralChooser` controller i see my passed info

```
print("id:", idSet)
print("name:", nameSet)
```

BUT, i cannot set this string on my button`s text!

```
rimB.setTitle(nameSet, for: .normal)
```

What is the problem? Perhaps i need to redraw my controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The major problem I can see from your code is that, you presented ChooserPopupViewController on GeneralChooser instance 1. Then when selecting a cell on ChooserPopupViewController, you are creating another instance 2 of GeneralChooser, and present it on ChooserPopupViewController while it is being dismissed. So I am pretty sure you are seeing the original GeneralChooser instance 1 after you dismiss the ChooserPopupViewController, but you passed the idSet and nameSet to the dismissed GeneralChooser instance 2. That is not how you should be passing info back from a presented view controller. Check this tutorial for different ways you can do it (specially sections with properties, delegation or closures)

https://learnappmaking.com/pass-data-view-controllers-swift-how-to/

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a delegate to pass back the information. what you're actually doing is creating an entirely new instantiation of GeneralChooser and setting the variables there. Which is why you're not seeing the changes being made on the original GeneralChooser.

What you should be doing is:

1) creating a protocol to act as a delegate

2) Add a delegate method to the protocol that GeneralChooser would need to implement

3) Add a delegate variable within ChooserPopupViewcontroller and have GeneralChooser set it to "self" prior to presenting "ChooserPopupViewController.

4) Have ChooserPopupViewController call the protocol method from the delegate variable, in order to pass back the information to GeneralChooser. Then update the GeneralChooser button title, prior to dimissing the ChooserPopupViewController.

Hope this helps!